# Convert time interval to seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi having trouble returning the value in seconds. Right now it is just returning mutiple 1's like this 1111111111111111111111111111111111111.

Should be returning 4220.

my input is 1 10 20 for example.

any help appreciated!

thanks

```
# File: WS01p1.py
# Write a program that prompt to read a time interval in hours,
# minutes and seconds and prints the equivalent time in just seconds.

x,y,z = input("Input: ").split()
print(x*3600 + y*60 + z)
```

Comment: The output isn't 1111111111111111111111111111111111111, it's 1111111111111111111111111111111111111...0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101020. This is an important point. It illustrates your root cause: string concatenation instead of integer addition. Convert your input to `int`S

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn the input into `int` value instead of `str`, which is assigned to`x, y, z` after `split()`. You can convert a `str` object to `int` using `int(<var>)` function. So in this case, it would be

```
print(int(x)*3600 + int(y)*60 + int(z))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be explained thus:

```py
>>> print('1' * 7)
1111111
```

When you "multiply" a string `s` by an integer `n`, you get a string of `n` copies of `s`. What you need is an *integer* multiplied by an integer. You can convert a string with `int()`, such as:

```py
vals = input('Input: ').split()
try:
    hrs  = int(vals[0])
    mins = int(vals[1])
    secs = int(vals[2])
    print(f'That is {hrs * 3600 + mins * 60 + secs} seconds')
except:
    print('Invalid input')
```

---

And, just as an aside, I don't know whether that's your real code or something you threw together to post here, but you should probably choose better variable names if the former. Anyone seeing `x/y/z` will almost certainly assume you're doing something with a 3D cartesian coordinate system rather than time-based stuff :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the `int` function to each of the values you get from `split()` in order to turn them from base-10 `str` values to `int` values.

```
>>> h, m, s = map(int, input("Input: ").split())
Input: 1 10 20
>>> print(h*3600 + m*60 + s)
4220
```

Answer (score 1):

x, y, z = map(int,input("Input:").split())

print(x,y,z)

`Input: 1 10 20`

`Output = 4220`

Comment: Next time remember to change ```str```  to  ```int```.  I hope this helps